# Export object with vertex paint

Tags: vertex-paint

I am a beginner when it comes to Blender, so bare with me.

I painted my sculpted character with vertex paint. Now I would like to export it to .obj or something like that, and if I have understood correctly it should be possible(?) But the colors doesn't show after exporting.

I have tried .ply too, but it doesn't work either. I have searched tutorials etc. from YouTube and internet and made "Attribute" node to the "Col", but it still does nothing. I really like how the paint turned out, so it would be a shame to start over.

(Hopefully my problem is understandable, English is not my first language. :D)

Comment: Hi. Is your question about exporting vertex colors to a file or rendering vertex colors in Blender?

Comment: Did you used experimental Sculpt Vertex Paint tool or regular painting in Vertex Paint mode?

Answer (score 2):

For render - ensure *Vertex Color* name matches with the *Name* in *Atribute* node field.

For export -

- **PLY** - exporter works for me (vertex color option is enabled by default)
- **ABC** - exporter can also store vertex color data, just enable it in export options
- **OBJ** - exporter doesn't have this feature. So you can export as PLY or ABC and use free app Meshlab to export as OBJ with vertex color.

Alternatively you can **Bake** vertex color into texture.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Are you sure Eevee does not render vcol?

Comment: @lemon Ha ... sorry, right. I was on old comp where eevee is not working. Thank you ... edited

Comment: ply should work... maybe something else is involved in the question...?

Comment: Thank ypu for the answers!
I have tried everything, execpt baking the vertex color to texture, since I am not sure how to do it. I thought the ply should work but I don't understand what is going wrong, hmm

Comment: As @lemon commented - are you asking to "export" or "render" vertex colors? For PLY you don't have to Bake image texture.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant exporting it

Comment: OK if we speak about exporting to OBJ or PLY does answer solved your issue? Or issue persists?