# Bake Mesh Analysis and Render into Model

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, color, obj

My experience with blender is minimal so I've been having difficulties with this. My goal is to have a 3d model in an obj format that is colour coded to thickness of the model. Having gone through some other questions, this has helped me greatly :[Bake Mesh Analysis to Texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73736/bake-mesh-analysis-to-texture/191739#191739?newreg=1ad37bafdb26411f8c392de96d2f2e18)

But right now when I export the file, the model is not coloured. I assume that it is because the colours are only in render and not in the solid object? How do I bake the colours in?

Comment: Why would you color code it like that when you can give it actual 3D thickness before exporting?

Comment: The idea is to 3d print it with the colours on the model itself!

Comment: I assume you want to [bake material](https://imgur.com/xWv37i8) into single image texture and map it by UV coordinates, right? Do you have any specific issue to follow some bake tutorial? Like that you will export mesh and texture file ... or do you need export mesh with [color information stored by vertices](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/200782/2214)?